# How do you Make a GraphWin Window in the center of the screen?

Tags: python, graphics

I'm making a simple game, specifics not important, and I want to make it full screen. I've been searching through, and I can't find how to make a graphics window centered. I can find the width and height of my screen, but anything simple like:

What I did and tried is on this document, because I'm having issues with stack overflow posting.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Gz1c63gbByNWq13dhHLdCnoHdoUvh6tfVvg41uRD9CQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Code shared in the link instead of question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd want to center the actual window, try `win.setCoords(width / 2, height / 2, -width / 2, -height / 2)`.

Comment: Didn't work sadly... From what I can tell, that's a superimposed coordinate system for objects. It doesn't apply to the window itself.

Comment: What do you mean? You specifically asked how to make a graphics window center, and this should work.

Comment: I want to make a 1400 * 800 graphics window automatically be in the center of my screen. The code you gave changes drawn objects, but not the actual window.

Comment: Does that clear it up a bit?

Comment: Yep, I'm still trying to figure out a fix to your solution.

Comment: I've been taking a look at the source code in tinker, but it's impossible to find what I need, considering it's 21,000 lines long. Also, I've never really messed with the source code of my modules, so I don't have as much experience in that.

Comment: Right now, it seems to recenter depending on where my mouse is when I open it.

Comment: I've never really worked with the graphics module to have a concrete answer, as I'd think that simply just dividing the height and width by 2 would work. And it usually does in any other case, but it's weird that it doesn't just work out of the box.

Comment: Here's an answer, but for Tkinter. Just simply change the values to whatever you want (1440x800, I did 500x500 just to test it out)

`import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
xoffset = (screen_width - 500) / 2
yoffset = (screen_height - 500) / 2
root.geometry("500x500+%d+%d" % (xoffset, yoffset))
root.mainloop()`

Comment: I believe that the setCoords is a superimposed system for objects in that win. Basically, setCoords is based of the GraphWin system. What really doesn't make sense here is that there's not a seperate function to set the GraphWin cords

Comment: Fair, again I wouldn't know too much due to me not really caring for or using much of the graphics module. I hope my current answer has helped!

Comment: I see, the only issue I have with that solution is it doesn't allow me to continue without learning an entire module. I can't do something like draw a rectangle using graphics.py onto a tkinter window.

Comment: What module do you use? And thank you, it did help some.

Comment: For graphics, I typically use SDL or Tkinter, and to draw a rectangle using Tkinter, you can simply make a new canvas, pack it, and call create_rectangle, like so.

``canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=100)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_rectangle(25, 25, 150, 75, fill="blue")``